# Finding all functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ with $f(f(n)) = an$, $a\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: co.combinatorics

The problem is to find all functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ for which there is a natural number $a$ and $f(f(n)) = an$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

I’ve already found two families of functions, either the identity function or 2 cycles of the form $$m_i \mapsto n_i \mapsto m_i$$
for every integer $i\geq 1$ of pairs $(m_i, n_i) \subseteq \mathbb N^2$, $i\geq 1$. In this case $m, n$ would not be multiples of $a$, so $f$ permutes one of $m, n$ to multiples of $a$.

but I’m having difficulty showing that all such functions must be identities or these 2-cycles. Any hints\tips would be appreciated.

Comment: For $a=1$ we get all involutions (there are continuum many). For $a>1$ this map consists of a disjoint union of countably many 1-sided shifts (orbits being of the form $a^\mathbf{N}b$ for $b$ nonzero mod $a$). To define a square root one has to pairwise associate the orbits (there are continuum many ways to do so). Once two orbits are associated, there are two ways to define a square root on the union of the two orbits.

Comment: @YCor, Im not very familiar with orbits, sorry. I only know what an orbit is but not much beyond that. Can you describe that differently?

Comment: FYI, from yesterday on Math SE, there's [Finding all functionals over $\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(f(n)) = an$ for which $a\in\mathbb{Z}^+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4757129/602049).

Comment: @JohnOmielan yes I saw that, but the proof for uniqueness was left as an exercise in the accepted answer.

Comment: Even adding the condition that $f$ be increasing, there are uncountably many such functions for $a≥4$: this is proved in the paper “[On integer sequences whose first iterates are linear](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00010-004-2750-x)” by Allouche, Rampersad & Shallit (2005), where the functional equation is studied in detail.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator\N{\mathbf{N}}$The set of square roots always has continuum cardinal. Let me provide the easy argument.

I assume $0\in\N$ but assume the question is about $\N_{>0}$ (adding zero doesn't change much, since fixed points have to fix zero. Observe that the question is purely a question of finding square roots of some specific elements in the monoid of self-injections of $\N$.

Write $g_a(n)=an$. For $a=1$ the question is about finding all involutions in the symmetric group of $\N$ and is thus quite trivial — this is canonically in bijections with the set of partitions of $\N$ into subsets of cardinal $\le 2$. This is a set of continuum size. Now assume $a>1$.

Let $R_a$ be the set of square roots of $g_a$ for composition. Let $X_a$ be the set of elements of $\N$ that are nonzero modulo $a$. Let $Y_a$ be the set of pairs $(M,u)$ where $M\subset X_a$ and $u$ is a bijection from $M$ to $X_a\smallsetminus M$. This is obviously of continuum cardinal.

I claim that there is a canonical bijection from $Y_a$ to $R_a$.

More precisely, given $(M,u)$ in $Y_a$, define $f(a^mx)=a^mu(x)$ for $x\in M$, define $f(a^mx)=a^{m+1}u^{-1}(x)$ for $x\in X_a\smallsetminus M$. This is well-defined, because every element of $\N_{>0}$ uniquely writes as $a^nx$ for some $x\in X_a$. Then $f\circ f=g_a$. Write $f=\Phi(M,u)$.

So we have defined a map $\Phi:Y_a\to R_a$. Then $\Phi$ is injective. Indeed, if $f$ is given, then $M$ is exactly the complement of the image of $f$, and $u$ is equal to $f$ on $M$.

To see the surjectivity of $\Phi$, let $f$ be a square root of $g_a$. Let $M$ be the complement of the image of $f$. Since $a\mathbf{N}_{>0}$ is in the image of $f$, we have $M\subset X_a$. Since $f$ is injective, we see that $f(M)\subset X_a$. Clearly $M$ and $f(M)$ are disjoint. If $y\in X_a\smallsetminus M$, $y=f(x)$ for some $x$; if by contradiction $x\notin M$, $x=f(f(z))$, so $y=f(f(f(z))=af(z)$, contradiction. So $X_a=M\sqcup f(M)$. Since $f$ commutes with $g_a$, we readily see that $f$ is given by the above formula. Hence $\Phi$ is surjective.

---

Note: as you know, a permutation of a finite set decomposes into finite cycles. For a permutation of an arbitrary set, one still has a "cycle" decomposition but it can include bi-infinite cycles (such as $n\mapsto n+1$ on $\mathbf{Z}$). For self-injections, we have in addition to allow one-sided "cycles" (such as $n\mapsto n+1$ on $\mathbf{N}$). When passing a self-injection to its square, the cycle (or "orbit") decomposition can be described: a finite cycle of odd length is unchanged, and other ones are split into two cycles: those of even finite length are split into two of half the length, bi-infinite resp one-sided infinite are split into two of the same type.

Here the square is just given by infinitely many one-sided cycles. So a square root is obtained by associating pairwise the cycles; on a union of two one-sided cycles, there are exactly two square roots. I formulated this slightly differently above.